# Angularjs - Loading view dynamically using

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to add a new component built with angular to my asp.net site. When running the component separately,everything works fine , but when the component loaded using jquery ajax request after angularjs was bootstraped the controller is not bound to the view. I wrote a little example the demonstrate my problem in plunker. Any help will be appreciated :
     [Code Example](http://tinyurl.com/pc3rz8h)

Comment: Just use [Angular UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for example